# vue-yandex-map, получаю ошибку e3

Tags: vue.js, yandex-maps-api

vue3, composition api, ts.
Устанавливал так: `npm install vue-yandex-maps`
Использовал так:

```
import { yandexMap } from 'vue-yandex-maps'
<yandex-map :coords='[event.longitude, event.latitude]' />
```

Ошибка выглядит так:`TypeError: e3 is not a function`
Что я делаю не так и как победить?

Comment: Почему решили, что e3 как-то относится к API Яндекс? Где остальной код? У Яндекса явно иной способ интеграции API 3.0 описан — более полный.